# Detecting if a touch pressed, not if its down?

Tags: c++, touch, sfml

i will make a beat em up game with sfml c++ on mobilephone. So i need to use the Touch function. The problem I have is, what is the best way to detect when the Touch has been pressed, and only execute the code which should be executed when the key has been pressed once? I need it for an animation when the Player make a kick. Now its always repeating the spritesheet animation loop, i wanna fix that, here is the a piece if my code where i need it:

```
...

if(animHit == true){
    
if(plrClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 0.1)
{
animRec.x ++;
if(animRec.x * 103 >= plrtex.getSize().x)
animRec.x = 0;
plrClock.restart();
}
}

FloatRect touchButtonRect = btnSprite.getGlobalBounds();

// the Touch is pressed the button
if(touchButtonRect.contains(worldPos)){


    animHit = true;

}
else
{
    
if(animRec.x * 412<= plrtex.getSize().x){
animHit = false;
}
}
```

Comment: please make sure to put minimal amount of code needed to replicate the error

Answer (score -1):

You haven't shown the minimal amount of code needed to replicate the problem, but i think i know where the problem lies. You most likely are trying to get the touch in the while loop without any events. Events are the things that tell your program to run things at, well, a trigger of sorts. This trigger can be a mouse click, resize of window, keyboard buttons or touch events.

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
int main()
{
    // create the window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
            
            if (event.type == sf::Event::TouchBegan)
            {
                //do something
            }
            
            if (event.type == sf::Event::TouchEnded)
            {
                //do something
            }
            
            if (event.type == sf::Event::TouchMoved)
            {
                //do something
            }

        }

       
        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...

        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With events you can use the triggers really well such as a screen touch. Using touchBegan it will record the single screen touch, even if you hold down the touch it will still be considered single touch.

Hope this helped.